# Get JSON Multidimensional Array Keys - AngularJS

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs, json

I am trying to build a form out of a JSON array. I need to load the keys into the HTML. Here is an example of this array:

```
{
  "Fred": {
     "description": "A dude"
  },
  "Tomas": {
     "description": "Another Dude",
     "Work": {
       "Current": "No Employer",
       "Previous": "Enron"
     }
  }
}
```

What I was are the values Fred & Thomas. When I run this in Angular HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="set in sets">
  <p ng-repeat="(key, val) in set">
    <span ng-bind="key"></span>: <span ng-bind="val"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

I get the error "ngRepeat-dupes" although Fred and Tomas are not duplicate values. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: your data doesn't have any duplicates... how are you getting an error?

Comment: @Claies There are NO dupes in the above code. I put it in a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/C4XuA3kGEoDywhiZYfGL?p=preview .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the dupe error from a key being the same in both objects. You can fix it by using `track by $index`, however in the data you have provided, there are no dupes... see fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/t4q4nrfp/36/

IF you did have dupes in your data though you just add in track by $index (you can use other things as well index is generally a default) like so :

```
<div ng-repeat="set in sets track by $index"> << add here if you have dupes are this level
    <p ng-repeat="(key, val) in set track by $index"> << or here if dupes at this level
      <span ng-bind="key"></span>: {{val}} <span ng-bind="val"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Also, just to be clear, you are working with an object not an array.

Comment: It works! One note for future people. I had a JSON document which was being returned by a PHP build API. One extrax step I needed to do in the Angular controller was this:
`$scope.sets = angular.fromJson(response.data);`

Answer (score 0):

use `track by $index`:

```
<div ng-repeat="set in sets track by $index">
  <p ng-repeat="(key, val) in set track by $index">
    <span ng-bind="key"></span>: <span ng-bind="val"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```